# Recurring Events with Existing Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing **live** application with an `Event` model that looks like the following:

```rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products, through: :orders
  has_many :rsvps, through: :orders
end
```

My problem is that I now need to add in the functionality that will let a user specify that the event needs to be recurring (for which they'll set a schedule).  There are a couple of approaches I've thought of as follows:

1. Have a `schedule` and `parent_event` property on the `Event` model, for which I will trigger a background job after the event is created to create duplicate events in the DB with the `parent_event` pointing to the main event so that I can aggregate statistics on the main event (like total tickets bought, etc...).  This is the easiest route as all of the models references (`tickets`, `rsvps`, `orders`) don't need to be altered.
2. Create a `Schedule` model that is a `habtm` relationship with events, and make `tickets`, `rsvps`, etc... belong to that instead.  So I'd be creating one event with many `Schedules` attached to it for recurring events.

Option 1 seems really dirty, especially if users want to delete an event (I'd have to delete all of the duplicates then as well), but it would require the least amount of code-changes.  Option 2 seems like it could be the most scalable approach, but I feel like I may be overcomplicating this.  Any advice / examples would be appreciated.

Comment: If you think about how existing calendars support this option... frequently it's possible for a user to change the details of just one event (instead of all of them)... which speaks to option 1 being more likely.

Comment: This is true, it just seems like doing it this way is really error prone - such as if someone registers for an event in the future, and the owner tries to delete / update original event.  There are going to be a lot of queries and checking to be done through many of the relationships anytime someone wants to perform an actions on the event.  Maybe that's just going to be a necessary evil though.

Comment: Yeah... i think you can't get past the calendars-are-hard thing... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first option is the way to go. I have done some tests with Google Calendar and I think their model is similar to the one you are proposing. You can read Google Calendar documentation (I provide some links below). As far as I could read:

- A recurring event has many **instances**
- Instances are events
- Instances have a link to their parent event (recurringEventId)
- When you modify or delete a recurring event, you are asked if you want to modify or delete only this instance, this an the following instances or all instances.
- Recurring events have information about the recurrence (as specified in RFC5545). Recurrence information is including in the parent event (it is omitted for single events or instances of recurring events).

> An event is an object associated with a specific date or time range. Events are identified by an ID that is unique within a calendar. Besides a start and end date-time, events contain other data such as summary, description, location, status, reminders, attachments, etc.
>
> Types of events: Google Calendar supports *single* and *recurring* events:
>
> - A single event represents a unique occurrence.
> - A recurring event defines multiple occurrences.
>
> **Instances**
>
> A recurring event consists of several instances: its particular occurrences at different times. ***These instances act as events themselves.***
>
> Recurring event modifications can either affect the whole recurring event (and all of its instances), or only individual instances. Instances that differ from their parent recurring event are called exceptions. For example, an attendee can be invited to just one instance of a recurring event.

Official information about **Google Calendar:**

- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars
- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

Comment: Thanks for the Google Calendar examples.  I think this really is the best way to separate the data - by physically creating a new event per occurrence.  I'll have to make some helper queries to do check against the actions the user wants to take, such as modifying the schedule, data, etc...  It's a pain, but as Taryn suggested above, these is just a difficult domain to navigate through in the first place.  Thanks!